# Opening a Python written .txt file in SciTE vs Notepad

Tags: python-2.7, scite

I am performing some data extraction operations on a large number of experimental data sets. These data sets are .txt files. Once I extract the data, I perform some mathematical calculations on them and compile this data into NumPy arrays. After this, I write this array data into a .txt file in pretty table format.

The problem I am encountering is that, these pretty print .txt files open exactly as desired in a Notepad but when I open the same file in SciTE all the data columns and grid are messed up.

I earlier though that this might be because I am passing this array through my own pretty table file writer. However, I tried to open the pretty print table written from the Python 'tabulate' library in SciTe but I observe the same pattern.

Some snapshots for your reference:[With Notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u98hp.jpg) and [With SciTE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtpAO.jpg)

I am not sure what's going wrong or how I should troubleshoot. This is of importance because Notepad freezes when it tries to open large files and also
my supervisor uses only SciTE.

Comment: Open the .txt file in SciTe and make sure that SciTe uses for displaying it a monospace font.

Comment: Thanks !! That worked.